# Android USB Host Debug with Development

Tags: android

I searched already and many of the questions and answers are out dated now.

Most Android devices support USB Host these days.  I'm curious what suggestions you guys have for tablets that can be used for developing USB Host dependent apps?

I'd prefer to have a tablet that has both a USB for hooking up to debug through and another to connect the device that is required for our application.  Found a few, but they seem rather out dated.